# Need SQL Statement that computes values base on positive or negative column value

Tags: sql

I'm using SQL Server and looking for a statement that that each row will contain a computed number based on whether the column value is positive or negative.

For example, I have this data:

```
**Field_1**
 23.0
-12.0
 14.0
 -4.0
```

If Field_1 is positive the column value is multiplied by 0.50.   if the value is negative, it is multiplied by -0.25.   So in this example, the results would look like:

```
**Computed**
12.5
 4.0
 7.0
 1.0
```

I'm struggling with how to distinguish between positive and negative value to apply the correct factor of 0.50 or -0.25.  Something like this:

```
    SELECT Field_1 * (0.50 if Field_1 >+0 or -0.25 if field_1 < 0) as Computed from Table
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: [`case when`...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What if it is = 0?

Comment: @ScottHunter: Whatever you multiply with, it will still be zero... As long as nothing is specifically stated about zero, in this case, I think it's safe to assume zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `case` expression:

```
select (case when field_1 > 0 then field_1 * 0.5
             when field_1 < 0 then field_1 * -0.25
             else 0
        end) as computed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just query the column you can use case when -

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN field_1 > 0 THEN field_1 * 0.5 
         WHEN field_1 < 0 THEN field_1 * -0.25 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS computed
```

If you want to update the table the you can use something like -

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET    field_1 = field_1 * 0.5 
WHERE  field_1 > 0; 

UPDATE table_name 
SET    field_1 = field_1 * -0.25 
WHERE  field_1 < 0; 

EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.field_1', 'computed', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional option.  In this case the same table data is going to be used over and over again with different coefficients, so I don't want to update the field data.  But a good option to know about!

Comment: @MichaelMcmaster - Please leave an upvote if the answer helped! Thanks :)